# Future<V> and Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

How to ensure that the exception thrown by @Asynchronous method from EJB 3.1 methods are not silently eaten up by Future? 

I know one can use Future.get method to retrieve exception but it will wait till the computation is done, a problem in case no exception occur and you have to wait till the computation is over.

(Update)

The scenario is fairly simple. A stateless EJB exposes its method with @Asynchronous annotation, primarily intended for @Local. The AS is JBoss. During computation, its possible that a RuntimeException occurs. Clients may or may not want to poll if the job is finished, but in all cases they should know if exception has occurred. 
A workaround is possible to use some sort of callback, but I am interested if there is any out of box solution available.

Comment: In case of exception , AFAIK , `Future.get()` returns immediately throwing the exception. I do not understand your last statement clearly. If there is no exception , obviously there is nothing to bother about until the computation is complete , right ?

Comment: @Bhaskar right, except that the method won't return; taking away the benefit of asynchronous call. I hope its clear now.

Comment: well, my question is why you want to make an asynchronous method synchronous while keeping asynchronous. :)

Comment: Yup , got it.Have you tried customizing your `ThreadPoolExcutor` with a `ThreadFactory` that produces `Thread` which have their `UncaughtExceptionHandler` set ? I am not 100% sure it will work but its the best that comes to my mind immediately.

Comment: @MarianP: that's what exactly I do NOT want :). simply I need my exception, without making it synchronous.

Comment: @bhaskar Using your own threads in an application server is discouraged AFAIK

Comment: I agree with @Bhaskar.  Please update your question to explain your scenario in more detail.

Comment: @bkail: I have updated the scenario, if you need further detail please let me know

Comment: I understand the problem: you want your client to continue doing computation (or perhaps wait for several EJB async methods to complete), but you want prompt notification when an async method fails.  I don't have a good solution; a callback would kind of work, but you would miss exceptions from "container interceptors" (e.g., security or transaction).  You could try to compensate by keeping the logic in the async bean to a minimum and delegate to a "real" bean, but messy.  In any case, there's nothing built-in to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider invoking [Future#get(timeout, timeUnit)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) to return the control after the given time if no results are available (the computation is not finished)?
You can also invoke Future#isDone() prior to Future#get() to know if the processing is complete.

Either way, you still need to invoke Future#get(-) to get known what has happened and to be sure that the exception is not swallowed.

HTH.

Comment: The timeout case, doesn't improve much, it will force the client to wait anyways. If client uses isDone, then it must keep polling until its true, that is also no better solution. My plain requirement is "Go do the job and only let me know if something bad happens"

Comment: The problem is "only let me know".  What is the meaning of "me"? the caller thread?  There is only 2 normal way to "let" someone know of bad things happened in async processing:  (1) The caller thread know about the problem and handle it (Future.get() ), or (2) a separate pre-defined handling subroutine is invoked when bad things happened (e.g. UncaughtExceptionHandler, Error Queue in JMS etc).  However u seems not satisfied about these two solutions.  May u tell us what's your ideal way then?

Comment: As @AdrianShum said, 'someone' need to ask for processing result. By definition, asynchronous method invocation is 'hit-and-forget'. If you don't ask for the results (either successful processing or exception) you're not automagically informed about them.

Comment: For "someone need to *ask* for processing result", it is definitely talking about Future's case.  Future's get() or isDone() etc is for you to "ask" the result.  Just start the process, put the Future somewhere, and forget.  Let that "someone" inspect the Future you stored.

Comment: After registering the Future object 'somewhere', this 'somewhere' could poll the isDone() method and if it's ready and an exception occurs it can fire some CDI event. You can have a method which @Observes this event and reacts as you wish. This will give you the 'inform only if something goes wrong' option.

Comment: @PedroKowalski;@AdrianShum: Thanks for your time and effort. As you guys pointed out, one can get it working, but its messy. Please also read @bkail comments on the question

Comment: @anergy, you're welcome. However, why do you think that a solution which involves the event firing / listening is a 'messy' one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to your problem. The way countdownlatch is implemented is to notify the calling thread how many future tasks are done. [here](http://sycure.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/example-using-java-future-and-countdownlatch/) is an example hot to use countdownlatch. So implement a small synchronous class and add an instance to all callable objects while submitting. that shall work as callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the configuration of your EJB container and you can set the executor, then you could [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [addCallback](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback%28com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback%29) method. This method requires a `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` instead of an ordinary one. You will get this kind of future by setting the executor of your instance to a `ListeningExecutorService`. Guava provides a [factory method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator%28java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService%29) for decorating each ExecutorService as ListeningExecutorService, so you are free to use whatever ExecutorService you had beforehand.